# Ошибка парсинга JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, синтаксический-анализ, jsonp

Добрый вечер.

Понадобилось написать **json** парсер на **jquery**.

```
    $.ajax({
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
       url: "http://freeapi.domaintools.com/v1/ns.ge?   api_username=usename&api_key=e22f2-5352-4235-5363&callback=?",
      success: function () {
         alert('jsonp'); // тут уже ничего не работает!
      },
   });
```

После запуска выдает вот такую ошибку.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : - Chrome
SyntaxError: invalid label - Firefox
```

Погуглил,везде твердят о **callback=?**,и больше ничего..

Функция возвращает:

```
{"response":{"product_list":{"domain_profile":{"name":"Domain Profile"}}.....
```

Comment: @Limansk, возвращает или должна возвращать?:)

Comment: Возвращает правильно,но в блоке success уже ничего не работает.

Comment: Мне нужно любым способом избавиться от ошибки,ну или на крайний случай присвоить переменной этот возвращенный json.

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте все-таки сделать так:

```
success: function (data) {
     alert('jsonp'); // тут уже ничего не работает!
  },
```

А еще я бы на вашем месте добавил бы помимо success еще error и еще там кажется есть какие-то события. И посмотреть по дебаггеру, куда все-таки он зайдет при выполнении.

Answer (score 1):

Может сервер не поддерживает callback? 
Там должно быть примерно так:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['callback']."({param1:'value',param2:0});";
 ?>
```

Comment: Проблема скорее в том,что JS требует валидный JSONP,но скрипт возвращает просто JSON..и от этого никуда не денешься...

Answer (score 0):

Вы определяли вообще коллбэк?

```
function jsonp_callback(data){
//
}
```

Comment: А при чем тут это?data же ничего не содержит.

Comment: @Limansk, разве? А я вот думал что коллбэк функция вызывается и ей передаётся параметр, содержащий JSON. То есть фактически внутри `data` будет объект.

Comment: Нет,все парсится с сайта,и по правилу должно передоваться в переменную data,которая,как вы сказали,принимает json.Но увы,из-за непонятной ошибки,это не работает.

Comment: @Limansk, я даже проверить не могу - там бросает 403 ошибку. И JSON ошибка. Но при установке параметров "callback" не появляется ничего. Ну то есть обёртки, которая присуща JSONP, нет.

Comment: Правильно,я поменял username и уникальный id.